# rotated element's positioning absolute to the left top

Tags: html, css, rotation, position, css-position

I can't figure out how can I position my rotated element to the left top corner(of the body) with position absolute. I've just made a little example here:

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

And a css:

```
    div {
         font-size: 10px;
         transform: rotate(90deg);
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
     }
```

But it disappers from the screen. I don't know why...
Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #5533FF;
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

I've added a width and height to your div, and now it looks absolutely fine to me.
If there's anything else, let me know.

Comment: oh thank you so much! im dunb...

Comment: does it matter if i already have a font-size on it?

Comment: Nope, the only problem you will get is that the letters get send to the next line, in other words in will get cropped. If you want to prevent that, give a "min-width" in your css code instead of "width".

Comment: I have a new solution for my question! I edited my post so you can see it.